# Why there is a "array" in the result of split? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I want to split an array into sub-array. The original data is:

```
['4 2','1 4','1 4']
['4 1','4 1','3 1']
['3','2','1']
```

The result I want to get is:

```
['4','1','1']
['2','4','4']
['4','4','3']
['1','1','1']
['3','2','1']
```

So my code is:

```
raw = [['4 2','1 4','1 4'],['4 1','4 1','3 1'],['3','2','1']]
newraw =[]
for item in raw:
    #print item
    numberOfRow = len(item[0].split(" "))
    temp = np.empty((numberOfRow,5))


    for i in range(len(item)):
        test = item[i].split(" ")
        for j in range(len(test)):
            temp[j,i]=test[j]
    for it in temp:
        newraw.append(it)
print newraw
```

When I `print newraw`, I found problems: (1), the result contains non-integers, (2) the results contains `[array([...])...`, but I don't know why.

So is there any solution, or is there any simple way to get the result I want? Thank you~

Comment: Your data aren't normal. Some of are space-separated digits and some just digits. That'll make things a little screwy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you just do it like this?

```
x = [['4 2','1 4','1 4'],
['4 1','4 1','3 1'],
['3','2','1']]

res = []
for i in x:
    res.extend(map(list, zip(*(j.split(" ") for j in i))))
```

You could lose the `map` call if if you didn't mind having a `list` of `tuples`. Also I wasn't sure if you meant, you wanted to convert all the values to integers. Your example output doesn't show this, so I presumed you don't need to.

Output:

```
[['4', '1', '1'], ['2', '4', '4'], ['4', '4', '3'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['3', '2', '1']]
```

Comment: Your code perfectly solve this problem. I think I need to read the instructions of `map`, `zip` to fully understand your code. For now, I can not interpret how your code functions. Thanks

Comment: `map` is very simple it, just iterates over an iterable (list, string etc) and calls a function on each item. In this case it calls `list` and its purpose is to convert `tuples` (returned by `zip`) to lists. You can try removing it and seeing how the output is altered.

Comment: `zip` is a little trickier, but it's definitely worth figuring out, as it's amazing how often it can be used and can make code much more elegant. I won't try and explain it here, as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) do it better than I can.

Comment: The other thing to look at is the asterisk `*`, which expands an iterable into separate values, which are what `zip` needs to function as required. A simple example for `a = ['a', 'b']`, note the difference between `zip(a)` and `zip(*a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner in Python2 :-)

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[zip(*[x.split() for x in item]) for item in raw]))
[('4', '1', '1'), ('2', '4', '4'), ('4', '4', '3'), ('1', '1', '1'), ('3', '2', '1')]
```

What does that line do? Let's break it down (I'm assuming knowledge of chain, list comprehension etc.):

- Simplest example, and then we will build on it.

  ```
  >>> raw = ['4 2','1 4','1 4']
  >>> zip(*[x.split() for x in raw])
  [('4', '1', '1'), ('2', '4', '4')]
  ```

  `zip` does some sort of matrix transpose operation. Take some simple example, and try paper-pen approach. It isn't difficult.
- Next, let's try that over the entire list:

  ```
  >>> raw = [['4 2','1 4','1 4'],['4 1','4 1','3 1'],['3','2','1']]
  >>> [zip(*[x.split() for x in item]) for item in raw]
  [[('4', '1', '1'), ('2', '4', '4')], [('4', '4', '3'), ('1', '1', '1')], [('3', '2', '1')]]
  ```
- Pretty close, let's chain it!

  ```
  >>> raw = [['4 2','1 4','1 4'],['4 1','4 1','3 1'],['3','2','1']]
  >>> from itertools import chain
  >>> list(chain(*[zip(*[x.split() for x in item]) for item in raw]))
  [('4', '1', '1'), ('2', '4', '4'), ('4', '4', '3'), ('1', '1', '1'), ('3', '2', '1')]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You overcomplicated a bit, probably me too. I would iterate over `raw`, then for each inner array create a helper container (dict) that will hold as values extracted arrays, as keys position in text-arrays.

```
raw = [['4 2','1 4','1 4'],['4 1','4 1','3 1'],['3','2','1']]

res = []

for inner_arr in raw:
    temp_container = {}
    for el in inner_arr:
        for idx, splited in enumerate(el.split()):
            if idx in inner:
                temp_container[idx].append(splited)
            else:
                temp_container[idx] = [splited]

    res += temp_container.values()

print(res)
```

This will work for any number of elements in the "text-array".